# Programming Pearls - Find Missing Integer

Tags: java

I wanted to try to solve the question found in the Programming Pearls book:

> Given a sequential file that contains at most four billion 32-bit
>   integers in random order, find a 32-bit integer that isn’t in the file
>   (and there must be at least one missing — why?). How would you solve
>   it if you could use several external “scratch” files but only a few
>   hundred bytes of main memory?
>
> Bentley, Jon. Programming Pearls (Kindle Locations 390-394). Pearson
>   Education. Kindle Edition.

Instead of integers, I decided to work with bytes. Here is my implementation in Java:

```
public class Main {

    private static byte[] checkBytes = new byte[8];

    static {
        checkBytes[0] = ((byte) -128); // 1000_0000
        checkBytes[1] = ((byte) 64); // 0100_0000
        checkBytes[2] = ((byte) 32); // 0010_0000
        checkBytes[3] = ((byte) 16); // 0001_0000
        checkBytes[4] = ((byte) 8);
        checkBytes[5] = ((byte) 4);
        checkBytes[6] = ((byte) 2);
        checkBytes[7] = ((byte) 1);
    }

    private static final String inputFileName = "bytes.txt";
    private static final String temporaryFile01Filename = "01_temp.txt";
    private static final String temporaryFile02Filename = "02_temp.txt";
    private static final String temporaryFile03Filename = "03_temp.txt";

    private static final File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    private static final File temporaryFile01 = new File(temporaryFile01Filename);
    private static final File temporaryFile02 = new File(temporaryFile02Filename);
    private static final File temporaryFile03 = new File(temporaryFile03Filename);

    private static File smallerFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String fewerElementsIn = segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte(checkBytes[0], inputFile);
        stringBuilder.append(fewerElementsIn);

        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            makeCopyOfSmallerTempFile();
            fewerElementsIn = segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte(checkBytes[i], temporaryFile03);
            stringBuilder.append(fewerElementsIn);
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
    }

    private static String segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte(final byte byteToCheckAgainst,
                                                          final File file) throws IOException {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        final BufferedWriter temp_01_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile01));
        final BufferedWriter temp_02_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile02));

        int temp_01_counter = 0;
        int temp_02_counter = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            final byte b = (byte) scanner.nextInt();
            if ((byteToCheckAgainst & b) == 0) {
                temp_01_counter++;
                temp_01_writer.write(String.valueOf(b));
                temp_01_writer.newLine();
                temp_01_writer.flush();
            } else {
                temp_02_counter++;
                temp_02_writer.write(String.valueOf(b));
                temp_02_writer.newLine();
                temp_02_writer.flush();
            }
        }

        temp_01_writer.close();
        temp_02_writer.close();

        scanner.close();

        String valToReturn;
        if (temp_01_counter <= temp_02_counter) {
            valToReturn = "0";
            smallerFile = temporaryFile01;
        } else {
            valToReturn = "1";
            smallerFile = temporaryFile02;
        }

        return valToReturn;
    }

    private static void makeCopyOfSmallerTempFile() throws IOException {
        final File fileToBeCopied = smallerFile;

        final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileToBeCopied);
        final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(temporaryFile03);
        int readVal;
        while ((readVal = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
            fileWriter.write(readVal);
        }

        fileReader.close();
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Am I really using a few bytes of main memory, i.e. am I solving this right? (Please ignore the main memory used by Java due to instances such as BufferedWriter etc..)
- Is there any way to solve this problem without needing the 3rd temp file?
- Any comments on the code itself?

When I have a sample file with bytes from -128 to 127 (in random order..) and only 48 is missing, this program will print:

```
00110000
```

which is simply "48" in binary..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

The problem statement is to optimize the code in respect to memory usage. But Java is meant to keep the programmer away from such low level optimization. This means Java is simply the wrong tool for this particular kind of problem, in the sense that there are other languages out there giving better control on the memory foot print.

Therefore I'll only answer your last question.

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers.

#### Conventions

Naming Conventions are important to make the code readable not only for you but other progammers too. 
So please read (and follow) the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Eg.: your variable names have underscores but you should separate words in your identifiers by camel case only.

#### Avoid single character names / abbreviations

You have a *single letter variable* `b`.

Since the number of characters is quite limited in most languages you will soon run out of names. This means that you either have to choose another character which is not so obviously connected to the purpose of the variable. And/or you have to "reuse" variable names in different contexts. Both makes your code hard to read and understand for other persons. (keep in mind that you are that other person yourself if you look at your code in a few month!) The same is true for (uncommon) abbreviations. You might find them being obvious today, while you're actively dealing with the problem, but You might have to "relearn" them if you worked on something else for a while.

On the other hand in Java the length of identifier names names is virtually unlimited. There is no penalty in any way for long identifier names. So don't be stingy with letters when choosing names.

#### Choose you names from the problem domain, not from the technical solution.

It is somewhat hard to me to give a suggestion here since I did not fully understand your logic (because of the poor naming... ;o) ). But look at this:

```
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    final BufferedWriter temp_01_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile01));
    final BufferedWriter temp_02_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile02));
```

a better version might be:

```
    final Scanner bytesToCheck = new Scanner(file);
    final BufferedWriter matchingBytesTarget = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(matchingBytes));
    final BufferedWriter notMatchingBytesTarget = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(notMatchingBytes));

    while (bytesToCheck.hasNextInt()) {
        final byte currentByte = (byte) bytesToCheck.nextInt();
        if ((byteToCheckAgainst & currentByte) == 0) {
            matchingBytesCounter++;
            matchingBytesTarget.write(String.valueOf(b));
     // ...
```

## Magic numbers

your code has some magic numbers. This are literal values with a special meaning like here:

```
private static byte[] checkBytes = new byte[8];
//...
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
```

You should introduce constants with meaningful names or or depend on properties so that the values are consistent:

```
private static final int SKIPPING_FIRST_INDEX = 1;
private static final int NUMBER_COUNT = 8;
private static byte[] checkBytes = new byte[NUMBER_COUNT];
//...
    for (int i = SKIPPING_FIRST_INDEX; i < checkBytes.length; i++) {
```

## Douplicate Code

In your method `segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte`
your `while` contains an `if` where the *behavior* in both branches is exactly the same, just the concrete identifiers differ. This branches are candidates to be extracted into a *parameterized method*. Here is how it goes:

#### change *similar code* into *identical code*

1. In the first branch of the if create  new variable (as first line):

   ```
   BufferedWriter outputFile = temp_01_writer;
   ```
2. Replace the following occurrences of `temp_01_writer` with `outputFile`:

   ```
   BufferedWriter outputFile = temp_01_writer;
   outputFile.write(String.valueOf(b));
   outputFile.newLine();
   outputFile.flush();
   ```
3. Do the same in the other branch:

   ```
   BufferedWriter outputFile = temp_02_writer;
   outputFile.write(String.valueOf(b));
   outputFile.newLine();
   outputFile.flush();
   ```

   now you have *identical code* in both branches.
4. Chose either branch and select the 3 lines that are identical with the other branch.
5. Invoke your IDEs automated refactoring *extract method*

   <sup>e.g.: in *eclipse* hit `<ctrl><1>` and select it from the popup menu.</sup>
6. choose a descriptive name for the new method (e.g.: `writeTo`), move `outputFile` th the first position in the list and cklick `OK`

   <sup>Your IDE replaces *both* occurrences of the identical code with a call to the new method.</sup>
7. double click the variable name `outputFile` in either `if` branch and invoke the IDEs refactoring *inline local variable*.  (in *eclipse* also available in the  `<ctrl><1>` popup...) repead this in the other branch of the `if`.

as a result (including the naming stuff) your while looks like this:

```
while (bytesToCheck.hasNextInt()) {
    final byte currentByte = (byte) bytesToCheck.nextInt();
    if ((byteToCheckAgainst & currentByte) == 0) {
          matchingBytesCounter++;
          writeTo(matchingBytesTarget, currentByte);
        } else {
          notMatchingBytesCounter++;
          writeTo(notMatchingBytesTarget, currentByte);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully you agree that this reads out much better...

## Single Responsibility/Separation of Concerns

In your method `segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte` you have two logical blocks:

1. distribute the values from the source file to the target files
2. evaluate the value counts of the target files to calculate the return value.

This two responsibilities should be separated to method of their own.

The problem is that you get  two values out of the first part but java can only return a singe value. so whe have to modify the code to enable the extraction  of the first  block to a method. the simplest possibility is to move the calculation of the condition `temp_01_counter <= temp_02_counter` out of the `if` statement by employing the IDEs automated refactoring *extract to local variable* (select the content of the `if`s braces and  hit <1> in *eclipse*...):

```
    boolean hasLessMatchingBytes = temp_01_counter <= temp_02_counter;
    if (hasLessMatchingBytes) {
        valToReturn = "0";
        smallerFile = temporaryFile01;
    } else {
        valToReturn = "1";
        smallerFile = temporaryFile02;
    }
```

Then move that new line  right behind the last brace of the `while` loop.

Now you can select the end of the method starting with the line `String valToReturn;`  until the closing brace of the method (excluding).

Invoke your IDEs automated refactoring *extract method* as we did before.

This modifies your code to this:

```
    // ...
    scanner.close();

    return calculateReturnValueBy(hasLessMatchingBytes)  ;
 }
```

Now you select the rest of the method from its beginning until `scanner.close();` (inclusive)  and extract that to a new method too:

```
private static String segregateBytesAgainstACheckByte(final byte byteToCheckAgainst, final File file)
        throws IOException {
    boolean hasLessMatchingBytes = distributeBytes(byteToCheckAgainst, file);
    return calculateReturnValue(hasLessMatchingBytes);
}
```

the extracted method looks like this:

```
private static boolean distributeBytes(final byte byteToCheckAgainst, final File file)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    final BufferedWriter temp_01_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile01));
    final BufferedWriter temp_02_writer = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(temporaryFile02));

    int temp_01_counter = 0;
    int temp_02_counter = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        final byte b = (byte) scanner.nextInt();
        if ((byteToCheckAgainst & b) == 0) {
            BufferedWriter outputFile = temp_01_writer;
            temp_01_counter++;
            writeTo(b, outputFile);
        } else {
            BufferedWriter outputFile = temp_02_writer;
            temp_02_counter++;
            writeTo(b, outputFile);
        }
    }
    boolean hasLessMatchingBytes = temp_01_counter <= temp_02_counter;

    temp_01_writer.close();
    temp_02_writer.close();

    scanner.close();
    return hasLessMatchingBytes;
}
```

## More code duplication

This last extracted method still has duplicated code which can be resolved by extracting a new *class* that handles the writing to a file. For shortness I just post the result as I would code it:

the new class:

```
  class BytesTarget implements AutoCloseable {
    private final BufferedWriter targetFile;

    // this name is ambiguous in the context of IO but its late at my place... ;o) 
    private int byteCounter = 0; 

    public BytesTarget(File targetFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.targetFile = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(targetFile));
    }

    public void write(byte currentByte) throws IOException {
        byteCounter++;
        // next lines move here and removed from class Main
        targetFile.write(String.valueOf(currentByte));
        targetFile.newLine();
        targetFile.flush(); 
    }

    public boolean hasLessBytesThen(BytesTarget otherBytesTarget) {
        return byteCounter <= otherBytesTarget.byteCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        targetFile.close();
    }

}
```

the changed method in Main:

```
private static boolean distributeBytes(final byte byteToCheckAgainst, final File file) {
    // "try with resource" avoids explicitly calling .close() on this variables.
    try ( Scanner bytesToCheck = new Scanner(file);
            BytesTarget matchingBytesTarget = new BytesTarget(temporaryFile01);
            BytesTarget notMatchingBytesTarget = new BytesTarget(temporaryFile02);) {
        while (bytesToCheck.hasNextInt()) {
            final byte currentByte = (byte) bytesToCheck.nextInt();
            if ((byteToCheckAgainst & currentByte) == 0) {
                matchingBytesTarget.write(currentByte);
            } else {
                notMatchingBytesTarget.write(currentByte);
            }
        }
        return matchingBytesTarget.hasLessBytesThen(notMatchingBytesTarget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // there is no way of recovering from an IO exception so just end the program.
        throw new RuntimeException("writing bytes to target files failed!", e);
    }
}
```